# Conditional insert of page breaks

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements

I have a form that is changing all the time and I have boxes of text in column "C". Also some text in cells of column "C" is too long so I am wrapping it with my VBA. I want to make conditional page breaks that will read through my Print Area and insert page breaks after each empty row before heading. My VBA code below is working fine except for text being wrapped. So the problem is: If I set `PgSize = 91` in `Sub FitGroupsToPage()` (that's an amount of rows could be fitted to each page) to 91 and don't wrap my text then everything works fine. However text must be wrapped to fit to my page. Then there is not 91 rows but less, according to the length of the text in wrapped cells. So number 91 is dynamic each time after hiding and wrapping `Sub FitMyTextPlease()` and `Sub HideMyEmptyRows()` and `Sub SetPrintArea()`. Number of rows can also be different on every page (depending of how much text there are wrapped on each page). Any ideas of how this issue can be fixed?

```
Sub FitMyTextPlease()
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Print version").PageSetup.CenterHeader = "&""Times New Roman,Bold""&12 " & Range("Data!V28").Text & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & " " & "&""Times New Roman,Normal""&12 " & Range("Data!V30").Text

    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Print version").PageSetup.CenterHeader = Range("Data!V28").Text

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Print version").Select
    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
            With .Cells.Rows
                .WrapText = True
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                .EntireRow.AutoFit
            End With '.Cells.Rows
            .Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With 'sheet
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Sub HideMyEmptyRows()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set myRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Print version").Range("Print_Area")
        For Each cell In myRange
        myRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        If cell.HasFormula = True And cell.value = "" And cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then Rows(cell.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Sub SetPrintArea()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim lastrow As Long

  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Print version")

  ' find the last row with formatting, to be included in print range
  lastrow = ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

  ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = ws.Range("A1:C" & lastrow).Address
End Sub
Sub Printed_Pages_Count()

    Range("A1").value = (ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Count + 1) * (ActiveSheet.VPageBreaks.Count + 1)

End Sub
Sub FitGroupsToPage()
    Dim rStart As Range, rEnd As Range, TestCell As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long, PgSize As Integer
    Dim n As Integer

    PgSize = 91   '  Assumes 91 rows per page
    Set rStart = Range("C1")
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Do
        Set TestCell = rStart.Offset(PgSize, 0)
        If Len(TestCell) = 0 Or Len(TestCell.Offset(-1, 0)) = 0 Then
                Set rEnd = TestCell.End(xlUp)
            Else
                Set rEnd = TestCell.End(xlUp).End(xlUp)
        End If
        ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=rEnd.Offset(1, 0)
        Set rStart = rEnd.Offset(1, 0)

    n = n + 1
    If n > 1000 Then Exit Sub   '  Escapes from an infinite loop if code fails
    Loop Until rStart.Row > lastrow - 50
End Sub
Sub FitMyHeadings()
Call FitMyTextPlease
Call HideMyEmptyRows
Call SetPrintArea
Call FitGroupsToPage
Call Printed_Pages_Count
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If standard row height is 15, then for 91 rows the total row height would be 1365. When text wraps one line, the row height becomes 30. So what you might try doing is defining 1365 as the total row height per page before inserting a break instead of 91 as the total number of rows.

You can determine the row height with `Range("A1").RowHeight`